# how to search sub directorys batch

Tags: batch-file

How can i modify this to make it be able to search sub directory's? i have tried a few different things but i cant seem to crack it?

```
set /p "folder=Folders Name that the photo's are in: "

setlocal
if "%folder%" == "" call :autodetect1
cls
for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
      if exist "%%d:\%folder%\" ( 
          echo Device was found on %%d: && set folderfound=%%d:\%folder%\
          ) else (
          echo Device was not found on %%d:
      )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the [`for /r`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) loop to iterate directories recursively:

```
for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    pushd %%d:\
    for /r \ %%p in (.) do (
        if exist "%%~p\%folder%\" ( 
            echo Device was found on %%d: && set "folderfound=%%~p\%folder%\"
        ) else (
            echo Device was not found on %%d:
        )
    )
    popd
)
```

**Short explanation:**
the `pushd` command switched to the drive with the letter stored in `%%d`.
 The `for /r` loop starts at `\` (the root directory of the currently selectly drive), and iterates runs all sub-directories.
`popd` returns to the directory before `pushd` was called.

This is just an example of how your loop should now look like. Everything else remains the same.

By the way, you are using `:autodetect1` in your script, but it is not defined anywhere...

Comment: sorry i didnt put that part in my bad

Comment: @Kysumi no problem, I just wanted to draw your attention to a potential problem, but it's not related to the answer anyway.